# Why does a FULL JOIN on all but one field return Null Values on that field?

Tags: sql, join, hive, outer-join

I am looking at the overlap and non-overlap (unique values) of users-ids from two different select statements using a full join. The main differentiation being that one table will have a deal_id = 0 and the other will have any deal_id greater than or equal to one. 
I am joining the select statements on exchange_id, pub_id, and user_id but not on deal_id. 
Here is my query:

```
SET
hive.auto.convert.join = TRUE
;

SELECT
    First.deal_id
    ,COALESCE( First.exchange_id, Second.exchange_id ) as exchange_id
    ,COALESCE( First.pub_id, Second.pub_id ) as pub_id
    ,COUNT (DISTINCT(case when Second.user_id is null then First.user_id else null END)) AS Incremental
    ,SUM (First.imps) AS First_imps
    ,SUM (Second.imps) AS Second_imps
    FROM
        (
            SELECT
                a.deal_id
                ,a.exchange_id
                ,a.pub_id
                ,a.user_id
                ,1 AS imps
            FROM
                logs a 
            WHERE
                a.deal_id >= 1
            AND a.event_type = 'TRUE'
        ) First 
        FULL JOIN (
            SELECT
                a.exchange_id
                ,a.pub_id
                ,a.user_id
                ,1 AS imps
            FROM
                logs a
            WHERE
            a.deal_id = 0
            AND a.event_type = 'TRUE'
        ) Second
        ON (
            First.exchange_id = Second.exchange_id
            AND First.pub_id = Second.pub_id
            AND First.user_id = Second.user_id
        )
        GROUP BY
        COALESCE( First.exchange_id, Second.exchange_id )
        ,COALESCE( First.pub_id, Second.pub_id )
;
```

Here are the results I am seeing:

```
DEAL_ID    EXCHANGE_ID    PUB_ID    INCREMENTAL    FIRST_IMPS    SECOND_IMPS
/N         4              1780      0              0             15
/N         4              1560      0              0             32
3389       4              1780      2              7             6
1534       4              1560      4              9             8
```

And here is what I would like to see:

```
DEAL_ID    EXCHANGE_ID    PUB_ID    INCREMENTAL    FIRST_IMPS    SECOND_IMPS
3389       4              1780      2              7             21
1534       4              1560      4              9             40
```

Where the results with a null deal id match up to the results with a non-null deal id based on exchange_id and pub_id.

What can I do?

Edit:
For clarification - 
The query I typed up is a simplification of my original query which requires two separate select statements since I am doing an Union with another events table. I didn't show it here since it's not related to the aggregation on Full Join issue. 
Also the incremental value is trying to calculate users who are present in deal_id >= 1 and not present in deal_id = 0 (another reason for the full join).

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems way overcomplicated.  You can use conditional aggregation for the query:

```
select min(case when l.deal_id >= 1 then l.deal_id end) as deal_id,
       l.exchange_id, l.pub_id,
       count(distinct case when l.deal_id >= 1 then l.user_id end) as incremental,
       sum(case when l.deal_id >= 1 then 1 else 0 end) as imps_1,
       sum(case when l.deal_id = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as imps_0
from logs l
where l.event_type = 'TRUE'
group by l.exchange_id, l.pub_id;
```

The only column I am not sure about is the `deal_id`.  But this seems to be the logic that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The query I typed up is a simplification of my original query which requires two separate select statements since I am doing an Union with another events table. I didn't show it here since it's not related to the aggregation on Full Join issue.
Also the _incremental_ value is trying to calculate users who are present in deal_id >= 1 and not present in deal_id = 0 (another reason for the full join) I don't think this query reflects that. (I've edited my question to help clarify)

Comment: @LMP . . . This query definitely calculates the `incremental` value correctly (according to your definition).  I don't know what the other `events` table might be doing.  It is only possible to address the question being asked.

Comment: I believe your definition of incremental is including in it's count the cases where the user_id is also present in l.deal_id = 0, I want to count distinct only the case where where the user_id is not present in deal_id = 0 but is present in deal_id >=1